# Why won't my PS3 connect to my Sony monitor?

Tags: technical-issues, ps3

I have a old sony monitor and I want to connect my ps3 by hdmi and it says that the only resolution the monitor supports is 1280x1024, but there is not resolution on the ps3 that works.

Here's the error I'm seeing:

[image: Out of Range: Input 1: DVI-D]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to connect an SXGA (1280x1024) monitor ratio to a PS3. 
In the PS3 manual under Video Output Settings it says the HDMI connector supports the following formats:

NTSC: 1080p / 1080i / 720p / 480p

PAL: 1080p / 1080i / 720p / 576p

They are all widescreen formats with an aspect ratio of 16:9. Unfortunately your older computer screen with an aspect ratio of 5:4 cannot display that; unless it somehow supports picture scaling or adding black bars at top and bottom.